# Getting incompatible integer to pointer conversion error in program. Unsure how/why exactly this is occurring but looking for an explanation

Tags: c, char, c-strings, function-definition, strchr

I'm trying to count how many dashes "-" there are in char p[]. I loop over the string, and use the strcmp function to compare what is at the p[i] location to "-". The strcmp function returns 0 if the they are the same.

```
int howmanyDash( char p[] ){
    int length = strlen(p);
    int i, count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(p[i], "-") == 0)
        {
            ++count;
        }   
    }

    return count;
    
}
```

```
int main(){
    char word[20];
    scanf("%s", word);
    int dashCount = howManyDash(word);
    printf("Dashes: %d\n", dashCount);

    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting reads as follows:
warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
if (strcmp(p[i], "-") == 0)

This warning was generated on line 7: if (strcmp(p[i], "-") == 0)

Comment: Your question should include the exact error (especially which lines is causing it)

Comment: Didn't you get any compiler warnings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `strcmp` has the following declaration

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

As you can see the both its parameters have the pointer type `const char *`.

But in you program in this call of `strcmp`

```
if (strcmp(p[i], "-") == 0)
```

you supplied the first argument `p[i]` of the type `char`. It seems you want to compare two characters

```
if ( p[i] == '-' )
```

You could use the function `strcmp` but you have to supply a string as the first argument of the function something like

```
if ( strcmp( &p[i], "-" ) == 0 )
```

This call of `strcmp` is semantically correct but the condition will evaluate to true only in one case when the string pointed to by the pointer expression `&p[i]` also represents the string literal `"-"`. In other cases the if statement will evaluates to false.

Pay attention to that the parameter of the function `howmanyDash` should have the qualifier `const` because the passed string is not changed within the function. And there is not necessary to use any standard C string function (though you could use the standard function `strchr`).

The function can be declared and defined the following way.

```
size_t howmanyDash( const char s[] )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for ( ; *s; ++s )
    {
        if ( *s == '-' )
        {
            ++count;
        }   
    }

    return count;
}
```

And in main you can write

```
size_t dashCount = howManyDash(word);
printf("Dashes: %zu\n", dashCount);
```

With using the function `strchr` the function `howManyDash` can be written the following way

```
size_t howmanyDash( const char s[] )
{
    size_t count = 0;
    const char c = '-';

    for ( ; ( s = strchr( s, c ) ) != NULL; ++s )
    {
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```